# parallel list comprehension using Pool map

Tags: python-3.4, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I have a list comprehension:

```
thingie=[f(a,x,c) for x in some_list]
```

which I am parallelising as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool=Pool(processes=4)

thingie=pool.map(lambda x: f(a,x,c), some_list)
```

but I get the following error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7f60b3b0e9d8>:
attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

I have tried to install the `pathos` package which apparently addresses this issue, but when I try to import it I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pathos'
```

Comment: Why won't you just use thingie=pool.map(f, some_list) ? Check if that works, I may have an idea.

Comment: well, a and c are defined seperatley, and need to be passed to the function, so I end up with errors.

Comment: My idea is that lambda is unpicklable, because you cannot get source code for that, so it cannot be sent to be executed in another process. Try Creating wrapper function, like def wrap_f(x): return f(a, x, c) and passing it to pool.map

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  `pathos` is *nearly* python 3.x compatible… but not yet.  So that's why it didn't work for you -- it failed to install.  The reason `pathos` can serialize a `lambda` is that it uses the `dill` serializer, which knows how to serialize a `lambda`.  `dill` serializes a `lambda` (basically) by serializing the code for the `lambda`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so this answer is just for the record, I've figured it out with author of the question during comment conversation.

`multiprocessing` needs to transport every object between processes, so it uses `pickle` to serialize it in one process and deserialize in another. It all works well, but `pickle` cannot serialize `lambda`. AFAIR it is so because `pickle` needs functions source to serialize it, and `lambda` won't have it, but I'm not 100% sure and cannot quote my source.

It won't be any problem if you use `map()` on 1 argument function - you can pass that function instead of `lambda`. If you have more arguments, like in your example, you need to define some wrapper with `def` keyword:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)

def f_wrapper(y):
    return f(1, y, "a")

pool = Pool(processes=4)

result = pool.map(f_wrapper, [7, 9, 11])
```

Answer (score 4):

Just before I close this, I found another way to do this with Python 3, using functools,

say I have a function `f` with three variables `f(a,x,c)`, one of which I want to may, say `x`. I can use the following code to do basically what @FilipMalczak suggests:

```
import functools
from multiprocessing import Pool


f1=functools.partial(f,a=10)

f2=functools.partial(f2,c=10)

pool=Pool(processes=4)
final_answer=pool.map(f2,some_list)
```

Comment: Neat, and frankly - better than my idea. Though, my answer shows the reason for problem.